# Printing in right to left

Tags: c++, c, winapi, window, gdi

In our product we support right to left. For this we apply the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` to the windows we create when needed. The `Win32` api `CreateWindowEx()` is used for creating windows. Hence every control created as a child window moves to the right and the vertical scrollbar goes from the right side of the window to the left side of the window. Also all painting in the HDC of the window is moved to the right. Windows takes care of this because of the class definition of the Window. Great!

However when we print we just write our text in a `HDC` and all works fine. However on Hebrew systems we still get Left to right output on the printer. As if the 0,0 is still in the upper left corner of the page. We use the standard PrintDlg() function which returns the HDC of the selected printer and here we do the simple drawtext() on the page. Exactly the same as we do in the Window we created. Hence the WM_PAINT message code is now called for printing and this works fine, however not for RTL.

Question:
How can I create a device context for the printer which mirrors the layout like the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` does for screen output?

Comment: Please provide a code which doesn't work, provide [mcve].

Comment: @jdekeij Try to use `SetLayout(hDC, LAYOUT_RTL)`，this seem work in window xp, refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1079e63f-8e24-472c-8c1c-a49f8b982d07/setlayoutlayoutrtl-does-not-work-properly-on-windows-7?forum=windowssdk) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this SetLayout(hdc, LAYOUT_RTL)  is where I was looking for.